# Change cursor with command line in actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, cursor, mouse

I want to change cursor during the running of the code in actionscript.
Is there a command to do that?

Example:

```
if (x<50) set mouse to hand

else set mouse to standard arrow
```

How to do this?

I don\t want to make an MC to act as a button. So  *MC.useHandCursor = true;* is not a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by adding a transparent button as big as the flash window is then hide it with code.
Then use  **_root.button._visible=true** when I want the mouse to change to hand.
It works well.